# Java best coding practices for low CPU Utilization

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, garbage-collection, aix

Can anyone give some tips on Java best coding practices for low CPU Utilization in AIX ?
For example like avoiding while(true) loops ,..etc
my requirement is my java application should run with low CPU usage so that it does not hog the other critical applications running in the same server

Comment: I assume there is no AIX specific code which needs optimising. i.e. the tag is not really needed.

Comment: Do you have one particular reason to ask this? Ie, a piece of code which troubles you?

Comment: Hi fge,my requirement is my java application should run with low CPU usage so that it does not hog the other critical applications running in the same server

Comment: @fge even if the OP has an idea of where to start, I would still say this could be a wasted effort unless some profiling has been done first.

Comment: @user1929905 Have you tried lowering it's CPU priority?

Comment: Enhanced my question further.pls check

Comment: @Peter,reducing CPU priority is the last option i planning to resort to.Before that i am trying to have the code consume less CPU.I am just searching for pratices which will hihlight coding ways to avoid high CPU usage

Comment: IMHO Lower the priority is just a temporary fix to give you more time to put in a proper solution. ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22038/discussion-between-user1929905-and-peter-lawrey)

Comment: I don't have access to the chat at the moment, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Run a CPU and Memory profiler, starting with the free VisualVM which comes with Java and optimise the code which is taking the longest.

Attempting to optimise the code without using a profiler is just guessing.

Note: Unless you are seeing no GC collections, allocating memory and discarding garbage uses CPU (and causes churn on your caches) so reducing it can improve your CPU usage and performance.

> my requirement is my java application should run with low CPU usage so that it does not hog the other critical applications running in the same server

I would start by lowering it's CPU priority until you have solved the problem.

Comment: Hi Peter,Actually my aim is to have a java application which does not take much of CPU

Comment: If you want to reduce your CPU it is a good idea to also reduce how much garbage you produce this also uses CPU, even if your total consumption is not an issue.

Comment: Enhanced my question further.pls check

Comment: @user1929905 I have replied to your comment above.

Answer (score 2):

As well as writing your app not to use too much CPU, you can also [prioritise applications](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aixprocesscontrol/index.html) using `nice`.

Very briefly, nice determines how much of the CPU resource a particular process can consume, and can ensure that other processes run ahead (get a higher time-share of the CPU).

Other tools/techniques exist - see the link for more detail.

Comment: I was thinking the very same, but are we really sure that nicing the VM will avoid CPU hogs ? I mean, having a strict while (true) loop will still hogs CPU

Comment: If you 'nice' appropriately, the time-sharing will allocate other processes ahead of the JVM. I can't say much more without more info on what precisely is running

Comment: of course, but at some time the VM process will have it's share of CPU and if the application is not well written we'll probably have a peak. I actually don't known how AIX scheduler works, so I don't know either what will happen. However for me is +1